# C++ s.replace function does not output spaces

Tags: c++, string, function, replace

I am trying to troubleshoot why a simple program to replace the word "yes" with the words "yes and no" will not work. I have concluded that having a space in the yes and no causes this issue. If there a way to get this program to work properly with the s.replace function?

Thanks!

```
string s = "yes this is a program";


while (s.find("yes") != string::npos) {
    s.replace(s.find("yes"), 3, "yes and no");
}
```

Edit: Below is the full program with a console input for the string.

```
int main() {
        string s;
        cout << "Input: ";
        getline(cin, s);


        while (s.find("yes") != string::npos) {
            s.replace(s.find("yes"), 3, "yes and no");
        }

        cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why use `while`? It's an infinite loop...

Comment: Add a cout to output s after the replace, and see if you can figure out what's wrong. (And for future reference, *will not work* is not a problem description that conveys any meaning or has any value, unless you explain **specifically** what you expected to happen and what happened instead.)

Comment: I am taking an input from the console for this program. I defined the finite string for the purposes of asking the question here.

Comment: Then you've picked the wrong mock text, because it apparently introduces a different problem. Read [mcve]. And read my comment again. It applies no matter where the input originates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands right now, this starts with:

> yes this is a program

It looks for `yes` in that, and replaces it so you get:

> yes and no this is a program

Then it searches and replaces again:

> yes and no and no this is a program

That's probably enough to make the problem apparent: since the replacement contains the value to be replaced, doing a replacement gets it no closer to finishing.

To make it finish at some point, after each replacement, we probably want to start the next search after the *end* of that replacement, instead of starting over from the beginning of the string, something on this general order:

```
string::size_type pos = 0; // start from the beginning

std::string replacement = "yes and no";

while ((pos=s.find("yes", pos)) != string::npos) {
    s.replace(pos, 3, replacement);

    // adjust the starting point of the next search to the end of the
    // replacement we just did.
    pos += replacement.length(); 
}
```